# What is an Isogeny in Complex Numbers?

Tags: number-theory, complex-numbers, elliptic-curves

Can someone give a simple explanation what it is meant to be an isogeny in complex numbers? I know that it is a homomorphism between two elliptic curves of the form $\mathbb{C}/L$ where $L$ is a lattice. But how can we show that a given map is an isogeny and find the elements of its kernel? It would be good if you can explain this via an example.

Comment: When is $z\to az$ well-defined from a complex torus to another ? Every complex torus isogeny is of this form.

Comment: @reuns: When $aL_1 \subseteq L_2$?

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}$